# how to change the color of an image on click(active) also how to revert it back on click of another image

Tags: jquery, materialize

I have 2 folders inside my image folder. The two folders are enableState and activeState. The enableState folder has white images(8 images in total) and the other folder has orange images(8 images in total).

I have sideNav appearing on the screen. All white images will be shown once the page loads. when the user clicks on the first image(white) it will become active and turns into orange.

But here is my issue, when the user clicks on the second image, the first image is still active(orange). I want the first image to be white when the user clicks on any other images(now other clicked image is orange) in the list

.

In this example, I have taken only 3 images into the picture.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul id="slide-out" class="col s2 m2 l2 sidenav sideNavBar">
<li><img src="/images/baseTemplate/enableState/gsymbol.svg" alt="G-Symbol" class="gSymbol_enable active"/>
</li>
<li><img src="/images/baseTemplate/enableState/commune.svg" alt="commune" class="commune_enable"/>
</li>
<li><img src="/images/baseTemplate/enableState/couplerhub.svg" alt="couplerhub" class="couplerHub_enable"/>
</li>
<ul>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
$("img").click(function() {
      alert("image");
      if ($(this).hasClass("gSymbol_enable")) {
      this.src = this.src.replace("/images/baseTemplate/enableState","/images/baseTemplate/activeState");
      } 
      else if($(this).hasClass("commune_enable")){
      this.src = this.src.replace("/images/baseTemplate/enableState","/images/baseTemplate/activeState");
      }
});
```

Comment: can you try this approach..whenever you click, first remove the active class, then add the active class to the clicked one ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("img").click(function() {

var allImg = $('img')
  

   $(allImg).attr('src','https://images.pexels.com/photos/556416/pexels-photo-556416.jpeg');    
      
      $(this).attr('src','https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/04/19/beach-1867285_960_720.jpg');
     
});
```

```css
li img { max-width:80px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slide-out" class="col s2 m2 l2 sidenav sideNavBar">
<li><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/556416/pexels-photo-556416.jpeg" alt="G-Symbol" class="gSymbol_enable active"/>
</li>
<li><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/556416/pexels-photo-556416.jpeg" alt="commune" class="commune_enable"/>
</li>
<li><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/556416/pexels-photo-556416.jpeg" alt="couplerhub" class="couplerHub_enable"/>
</li>
<ul>
```

Hey can you check , if this meets your requirement. Let know.

Comment: This did not work according to my requirement. On click, this is making all the sidenav images same.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my HTML code. I have renamed images as _on for activeState and _off for enableState. For example gsymbol.svg as (gsymbol_on.svg, gsymbol_off.svg).

<ul id="slide-out" class="col s2 m2 l2 sidenav sideNavBar">
<li><img src="/images/baseTemplate/enableState/gsymbol_off.svg" alt="G-Symbol" class="gSymbol_enable active"/>
</li>
<li><img src="/images/baseTemplate/enableState/commune_off.svg" alt="commune" class="commune_enable"/>
</li>
<li><img src="/images/baseTemplate/enableState/couplerhub_off.svg" alt="couplerhub" class="couplerHub_enable"/>
</li>
<ul>

Here is my JS code :

$(" .sidenav > li > img").click(function () {
  var allImg = $('.sidenav > li > img')
  $('.sidenav').children('li').children('img').map(function () {
  var allImgs = $(this).attr('src');
  allImgs = allImgs.replace("activeState", "enableState");
  allImgs = allImgs.replace("on", "off");
  $(this).attr('src', allImgs)
  }).get();

  var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
  imgSrc = imgSrc.replace("off", "on");
  imgSrc = imgSrc.replace("enableState", "activeState");
  $(this).attr('src', imgSrc);
});

This code makes the clicked image as active(orange) and rests as disabled(white).
```